# How to load HTML files dynamically when running locally? Avoiding Cross-Origin error

Tags: javascript, html

I have a javascript/html project and I'm loading html data from a relative location inside the project. But when I run on localhost without a web server I get a cross origin error.

I want to keep loading my data on the fly and I don't want to run a webserver. Cause when I share it, I'll share it as a zip file for people to run on their own local computers instead of through a webserver. I can't expect them to be able to run a webserver on whatever platform they have.

How do I solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to build a desktop application. Why do you think HTML is the best tool for the job? And if you build it in HTML/JavaScript, why not just put it on a server, for instance the server that contains that already contains that HTML file to download? Sharing a website as a zip file is *so*... well.. I can't find a right year, because people stopped sharing zipped documentation when the web was invented. ;-)

Comment: Have you looked into electron or nwjs?  That's the only way I can think of potentially adding the functionality you are looking for.

Comment: HTML is easy and cross platform! Also really fast. And I love making UIs in HTML. It's just so wonderful for writing quick and visually yummy applications. 

Electron looks like the best answer so far! Thanks.